# ^U does not kill despite stty claims

Tags: shell, terminal, signals, ubuntu-14.04, stty

**problem:**  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will not kill my terminal program.

---

**details:**  Here are my results from `ssty --all`:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

As you can see, it describes the available signal interrupts:
<kbd>^C</kbd> = <kbd>intr</kbd>
<kbd>^ \</kbd> = <kbd>quit</kbd>
<kbd>^U</kbd> = <kbd>kill</kbd>
etc ...

Here is an infinitely running program:

```
int main (){while(true){}}
```

---

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  works

```
$./main                                                             
^C
$
```

---

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>  works

```
$./main                                                           
^\[1]    6331 quit (core dumped)  ./main
$
```

---

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>  **does not** work.
Why can't I kill a terminal program this way?

I could of course find the process id and run `kill -9 <PID>`,
but I want the shorthand to work.

---

I'm on Ubuntu:

```
lsb_release --all 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

---

Here are my terminal specs, but I've tried other terminals (probably not relevant)

```
gnome-terminal --version                                           
GNOME Terminal 3.6.2
```

It didn't work on xterm either.  I've also tried different shells:
`sh`, `bash`, ans `zsh`.

What could the problem be?  Where should I look now?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/343031/sigterm-with-a-keyboard-shortcut and https://superuser.com/questions/288772/shell-sigkill-keybinding/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill` in `stty`'s output refers to the kill-line character, that is, pressing `^U` erases to the beginning of the line.

The characters that send an interrupt signal are `intr`, `quit`, `susp`, and on some systems (not on Linux IIRC), `dsusp`.

Comment: I see.  So there is no way to kill other than using `kill`?

Comment: Well, there is always the sysrq key (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), but that would kill every process on the current virtual terminal, or every process except init.

Answer (score 0):

To implement such a thing, you would have to add another signal, say `VPKILL` and `PKILL_CHAR` for `process kill` as opposed to the existing `VKILL` and `KILL_CHAR` in `include/linux/tty.h`; a new `else if` clause to `drivers/tty/n_tty.c` in the Linux source, and modify any other necessary header and driver files accordingly. I suspect this is easier said than done, as this logic is baked into Linux at a very low level, and there may well be assumptions in other parts of the kernel that will cause loss of stability and Heisenbugs.

```
    if (L_ISIG(tty)) {
            if (c == INTR_CHAR(tty)) {
                    n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGINT, c);
                    return 0;
            } else if (c == QUIT_CHAR(tty)) {
                    n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGQUIT, c);
                    return 0;
            } else if (c == SUSP_CHAR(tty)) {
                    n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGTSTP, c);
                    return 0;
            }
    }
```

I'll update this answer if I get over my fears and actually try it...